# redirect to url only if the destination url is valid

Tags: nginx

I have a redirect rule setup like this

```
#redirect old phpbb links to xenforo links
if ( $arg_p ) {
   rewrite ^\/forum\/viewtopic\.php /forum/posts/$arg_p/? permanent;
}
```

Which it will send a 301 to any url that matches that regex to the new format.

However I would like to know if there's a way to do this redirect ONLY if the destination URL is valid (in this context valid means it should not return a 404 or 403)

Comment: Why do you want this and what should happen if it's possible?

Comment: I'd like to return a clean 404 if destination URL doesn't exist, without redirecting first.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this easily, and it's unlikely that you really want to.

If you *could* do this, it would require a query to your web application for every single incoming request, *in addition* to serving the request itself, thus approximately doubling the load on your server. This could probably be done with some clever embedded Lua code, but I think you probably don't want to overload your server.

Better to just redirect everything and then let the destination (your new forum) serve a 404 if necessary. This doesn't really have any SEO impact, because the original links were 404s already. But it provides a better user experience, since incoming traffic to dead links will at least see the new forum rather than a plain white nginx 404 page.

Comment: Well, to be honest SEO IS the reason I wanted to do this. Looking in Webmaster tools I got tons of 404s which I believe are caused by outdated google index. Normally I would expect that after a number of tries google would stop trying to index those links. But it's been almost a week and the index hasn't been updated and I keep getting those 404s errors. I thought this is happening because of the redirects.

Comment: Google will keep trying 404s essentially forever, in case the page ever comes back.